# Inserting predefined value into textbox based on selection from dropdown list

Tags: jquery, asp.net, drop-down-menu, textbox, dropdown

I have simple dropdown list with 3 options to choose from and a textbox below. After the user selects an option I need its value to be inserted as a text into the text box - if customer selects "Employee 1", "TextBoxEmployee" will be filled with "1" and so on.

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="Assigned_Employee">
    <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="Employee 1">Employee 1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="Employee 2">Employee 2</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="Employee 3">Employee 3</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxEmployee" runat="server"/>
```

Can you suggest the easiest way to do it? Can I use jQuery for it? Thanks for the help :)

Comment: `$('#Assigned_Employee').change(function(){ $('#TextBoxEmployee').val(this.value);}`

Answer (score 0):

Please find [this](https://jsfiddle.net/zwpzx9wn/) fiddle it will help you

Add document ready function where you set textbox value predefined as per your dropdown selection while page load and change function will change value of textbox

```
$(function(){
  $("#TextBoxEmployee").val($(".changeclass").val())
})

$(".changeclass").on("change",function()
{
   $("#TextBoxEmployee").val($(this).val())
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For such thing you can choose native js as:

```
var sel = document.querySelector('#<%= TextBoxEmployee.ClientID %>'),
    inp = document.querySelector('#<%= Assigned_Employee.ClientID %>');

sel.addEventListener('change', function(e){
   inp.value = this.value;
});
```